# Nightwatch js can't click a tab

Tags: nightwatch.js

I m writing a night watch js e-t-e test for my site. My site has a right hand tabs that are use as a menu that allow user to navigate. Te problem is my niightwatch is not able to perform click on the tab. I tried everything possible to no avail.

```
.verify.elementPresent('div[role="tab"][title="Asset Index"]')
.click('#right-tab-list div:nth-child(5)', function(status){
        console.log('the click status is', status.status);
        browser.click('#right-tab-list div:nth-child(5)');
})
.waitForElementVisible('div[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"][title="Asset Index"]', 3000)
```

.verifying `div[role="tab"][title="Asset Index"]` present returns positive.  However, the click on the `div:nth-child(5)` of the `#right-tab-list` failed. The 5th child is the `div[role="tab"][title="Asset Index"]` . The click status returns -1.Before i my code was

```
.verify.elementPresent('div[role="tab"][title="Asset Index"]')
.click('div[role="tab"][title="Asset Index"]', function(status){
       console.log('the click status is', status.status);
       browser.click('#right-tab-list div:nth-child(5)');
 })
 .waitForElementVisible('div[role="tab"][aria-selected="true"][title="Asset Index"]', 3000)
```

verifying the element present returns true . However the click status returns negative . The proceeding `waitForElementVisible` failed as well. I tried everything possible to no aveil. It was working 4 months back though. I just am not sure why not today. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried verifying that #right-tab-list div:nth-child(5) is present before you try to click it?